# Your Ruby version is 3.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.8

Tags: ruby, xcode, react-native, macos, cocoapods

I'm getting this error message when I try to do a pod install on Mac on a Turbo Module in React Native. I believe it's because of my version of Xcode installed.

```
> RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec pod install
Your Ruby version is 3.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.8
```

When I run ruby -v it returns 2.6.8.

```
> ruby -v
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
```

I'm not sure what to do to fix this or where it's finding 3.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.6.8 is the builtin ruby in macOS Monterey, which can be found at `/usr/bin/ruby`. If bundle is finding 3.1.2 then you have another version of ruby installed (possibly via homebrew?). You can see all versions of ruby on your current `PATH` using the command `which -a`. The order of results is the order in which they are found on the `PATH`, as you can confirm by typing `echo $PATH`. Execution is on a first-come-first-served basis. On my machine the `which` command produces:

```text
% which -a ruby
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

showing that I have a homebrew copy of ruby first on my `PATH`, followed by the macOS copy.

Similarly, you can check which installation of bundle is being used:

```txt
% which -a bundle
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/bundle
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin/bundle
/usr/bin/bundle
```

You can override the `PATH` ordering by editing `.zshrc` (long-term change); by explicitly setting it to a new set of path values in the current terminal (one-time change for the active terminal window); or by typing the fully qualified path name of the version of the command you wish to run (ex: `/usr/bin/bundle ...` to use the system version).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! When I do `which -a ruby` I'm only getting one copy returned `/usr/bin/ruby`. Bundle gives me two `/usr/local/bin/bundle` and `/usr/bin/bundle`.

Comment: @BerryBlue That says that you have a local install of `bundle` which is aware of and uses a local install of ruby that is not on your `PATH`.  Are you using homebrew? If so, run `brew info ruby` to review the `PATH` guidance that was printed out when you initially installed ruby.

Comment: Ok, thank you! It was there but for some reason not showing up on which.

Comment: @BerryBlue `which -a` only shows executables that are on the `PATH`.

Comment: Ok, so homebrew uses ruby 3.1.2 with cocoa pods. Is there a way to change this? I can't seem to override that.

Comment: Which version of bundle/ruby do you actually want to use?